# Using Android systrace to get statistic frames data

Tags: android, performance, react-native, performance-testing, systrace

I want to get information about average FPS, number of dropped frames, average RAM usage in a text form, so that I can compare two apps and see which one is smoother when scrolling a list. But I need hard data for this (it's for diploma thesis).

When I run

```
$ <path_to_android_sdk>/platform-tools/systrace/systrace.py --time=10 -o trace.html sched gfx view -a <your_package_name>
```

recommended by React-native I get a lot of visual data and cannot get only what I mentioned.

Could you please provide me script that can get me the data I need?

Comment: did you find something?